# Difference between pooling and subsampling

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

At [this point in a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Svb1c6AkRzE&feature=youtu.be&t=634) on LeNet1, Yann LeCunn seems to make a distinction between pooling and subsampling, with a separate gesture for each:

> [...] The second version had a separate convolution and pooling layer and subsampling

I believe I understand what max pooling and average pooling do.  What is subsampling as a distinct operation?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-15825-4_10 It is proven that maxpool is better result compare to sub-sampling.

Comment: please check this link for answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53634696/13651716)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference. Pooling operation does sub-sampling of the image. You can find that people refer to subsample as an operation performed by pooling layer

[image]

In fact, in the paper they describe sub-sampling as a pooling layer

[image]

You can check Yann LeCun's paper [Gradient-Based Learning Applied to Document Recognition](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

There are different types of pooling, including **MaxPooling** and **AveragePooling**.
MaxPooling captures the maximum pixel value in a grid (say z x z) from the entire image and then processes that in output image. Average Pooling likewise calculates the average and processes that in output image.

On the other hand, **Subsampling** chooses a pixel in the grid and replaces surrounding pixels of said grid by the same pixel value in the output image.

The output image from these two might look the same (and might have no major changes in accuracy in the Neural Network), however, they are not exactly same.

Comment: So then max pooling is subsampling with the maximum value selected.

Comment: Exactly the point

Comment: In addition, sub-sampling produces trainable parameters whiles Max and Average pooling do not. Please refer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/265319/197343